# Select first instance of class inside ancestor with class

Tags: jquery, selector

Suppose I have this HTML structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">1 <!--This is what needs selected--></div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">2</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">3</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">4</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">5</div></td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

So I need to select via jQuery the first `.day` in the first `td` with the class `.hasDay`. I've tried the following:

`$("tr .hasDay:first-child .day")`

Looping through every `td` in the `tr`, stopping when it gets to `.day` and using `$(this)` to select it.

How do it do it?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:first-of-type`:

```
$("tr .hasDay:first-of-type .day")
```

And also `.first()` jQuery function works!

```
$("tr td.hasDay").first().find(".day")
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("tr td.hasDay").first().find(".day").css("color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>Not this!</td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">1</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">2</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">3</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">4</div></td>
        <td class="hasDay"><div class="day">5</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try, query first the class hasDay and then child with class day.

```
$('.hasDay .day').first().html()
```